# How to update state twice with asynchronous data in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is most efficient way to create state and update it in the same function that expects new asynchronous data.

```
const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([]);

const onSubmitImage = async () => {

  setGallery((prevState) => {
    return [
      ...prevState,
      { id: uuid, imgUrl: "", status: "loading" },
    ];
  });

  const response = await fetch("API etc..");
  const data = await response.json();

  updateGalleryState(uuid, data['imgUrl']); 

}

const updateGalleryState = (uuid, imgUrl) => {
  //I will find the element in state and place the response url from the API
  //{ imgUrl: imgUrl, status: "uploaded" }
}
```

As I need both state updates in the same function `onSubmitImage`, how can I prevent both queuing? - Or is there a better way to achieve this results?

---

Update:

This is my suggestion to update with `updateGalleryState`:

```
  const updateGalleryState = (uuid, imgUrl) => {
    const index = gallery.findIndex((element) => element.uuid === uuid);

    if (index !== -1) {
      let newGallery = [...gallery];
      let newObject = {...gallery[index]};

      newObject.status = "uploaded";
      newObject.imgUrl = url;
      newGallery[index] = newObject;

      setGallery(newGallery);
    }
  };
```

This wouldn't work because the update state happens twice and they queue, only the first `setGallery` is executed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to understand your issue and I don't find it. Your code seems fine to me. Could you explain further?

Comment: @NicolásLonghi, I added the update. Thanks :D

Comment: Mmm. I'm not sure that's why it's not working. Please try calling setGallery with a callback instead of a value (like you are doing the first time). So it would be like this:
```const updateGalleryState = (uuid, imgUrl) => {
  setGallery((prevGallery) => {
    // here you look for the index and return the updated value
  });
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry, that code I posted is all badly formatted. I hope you understand

Answer (score -1):

You should use `useEffect` to track every side effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
//updateGalleryState 
}, [gallery])
```